# How do I access values from a Dictionary in an object?

Tags: c#, javascript, object, dictionary

Alright, I'm not sure if I'm asking the right question, but here goes. I'm using [Javascript .NET](http://javascriptdotnet.codeplex.com/) to parse a Javascript object array. My code looks something like this:

```
object packlist;
using (var context = new JavascriptContext())
{
    context.Run(@"function packlist() { this.packs = new Array(); }
                var packlist = new packlist();
                packlist.packs[0] = { item1:""something"", item2:""something2"", item3:""something3"" };
                packlist.packs[1] = { item1:""something"", item2:""something2"", item3:""something3"" };
                packlist.packs[2] = { item1:""something"", item2:""something2"", item3:""something3"" };");
    packlist = context.GetParameter("packlist");
}
```

While debugging, the Locals window says the object looks like [**this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOHR6.png)
[image: this]
My question would be how would I go about accessing `item1` from `packlist.packs[0]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general structure is as follow:

```
PackList => Dictionary of <string, Dictionary<string,object>[]>
```

Meaning it is a dictionary where each value is an arry of dictionaries.

Should be

```
object[] arr = packlist["packs"] as object[]; 
Dictionary<string, object> dictPack = arr[0] as Dictionary<string, object>;
object item1 = dictPack["item1"];
```

Or

```
object packs;
if (packlist.TryGetValue("packs",out packs)) { 
     object[] arr = packs as object[]; 
     Dictionary<string, object> dictPack = arr[0] as Dictionary<string, object>;
     object item1 = dictPack["item1"];
}
```

The difference between them is that in the first, it is assumed that the key exists in the dictionary otherwise it throws an exception. In the second, it will try to get the value and tell you if the key is valid.

To check if a key is in the dictionary you can use this:

```
bool exists = packlist.ContainsKey("item1");
```

To run through all the items in the dictionary

```
foreach KeyPairValue<string,object> kp in packlist
{
    string key =  kp.Key;
    object value = kp.Value;
}
```

Here's the MSDN link for the dictionary class

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb347013.aspx

Comment: I'm not able to use the extension methods `TryGetValue` or `ContainsKey` on `packlist`. What do I have to do to get them?

Comment: You must parse it using: "Dictionary<string,object> packlist =(Dictionary<string,object>) context.GetParameter("packlist");" You'll probably have to parse the other values too. I updated my code.

Answer (score 4):

Your packlist variable is a Dictionary with a single key, with the value being a object-array and every entry in that array also is a Dictionary. So getting the value would go something like this.

```
Dictionary<string,object> dicPacklist =(Dictionary<string,object>) packlist;
object[] packs = (object[])dicPacklist["packs"];
Dictionary<string,object> dicPackOne = (Dictionary<string,object>)packs[0];
object item1Value = dicPackOne["item1"]; //"something"
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot with understanding how it works. I wish I was able to upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is:

var a = packlist.packs[0]["item1"];

Comment: packlist is a dictionary where each value is an array of dictionaries. This code won't work.